Multiple pie chart
May I have your help please? I'd like to create a multiple pie chart on the following data (see below). I have 33 sites, but here is just an example of the data.
Sites   Transect Genus        Number
  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>        <chr> 
1 ANKHAB1 T1       Cypraea      1     
2 ANKHAB1 T1       Diadema      2     
3 ANKHAB1 T1       Tridacna     3     
4 ANKHAB1 T1       Protoreaster 0     
5 ANKHAB1 T1       Atrina       0     
6 ANKHAB1 T2       Diadema      3 


What have you tried? What's not working?

What is the question?

Here is an approach on how to make and plot multiple pie charts. I found the following R graph gallery website to be helpful.
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# Create Data
data <- data.frame(
  group=LETTERS[1:5],
  value1=c(13,7,9,21,2),
  value2=c(20,22,8,14,3)
)

# Basic piecharts
p1 <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=value1, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

p2 <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=value2, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void()

# Use patchwork package to plot piecharts together
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 1)


p1 + p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 2)


Created on 2024-05-28 with reprex v2.1.0
